# One or more of entire regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to check a line from a text file and check with a regular expression if the input is valid.  What I am trying to do is check if the user entered a variable in java it would check to see if it is correct.

```
<?php

$intpat = "/^int\s[a-zA-Z_$]+(;$|\s*=\s*\d+;$)/";

?>
```

above is my expression to check, which works fine unless the user enters 2 variables on the same line.  below is the output I would like

```
int x = 5; valid
int y; valid
int x = 5; int y; valid
```

I have tried using `$intpat = "/^int\s[a-zA-Z_$]+(;$|\s*=\s*\d+;$)+/";`
but it still gives me false for the third line.

Comment: You can't use `$` (end-of-string) inside a (sub)expression that repeats. Or, at least, it will fail when the (sub)expression does repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
$intpat = "/^(:?int\s+[a-zA-Z_$]+(:?\s*=\s*\d+)?;\s*)+$/";
```

**[regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#/%5E%28%3a?int%5Cs%2b%5Ba-zA-Z_%24%5D%2b%28%3a?%5Cs%2a=%5Cs%2a%5Cd%2b%29?;%5Cs%2a%29%2b%24/)**